# Plotting with multiple y values with subplot and groupby

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, pandas-groupby, subplot

I have a `df`. See below for the head:

```
Country         Date     suspected case    confirmed cases   suspected deaths   confirmed deaths   

0   Guinea   2014-08-29       25.0            141.0              482.0              648.0
1   Nigeria  2014-08-29       3.0             1.0                15.0               19.0
2   Liberia  2014-08-29       382.0           674.0              322.0              1378.0
```

By using `df.groupby('Country')` I want to plot the `suspected case` against the `confirmed case` using the `Date` column for the `xaxis`. Plotting these as (5, 2) subplots

What I've done so far hasn't quite got it yet:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 5, sharey=True)
df.groupby('Country').plot(x='Date', y=['suspected cases', 'confirmed cases'], title=f'Suspected vs. Confirmed cases {country}')
plt.show()
```

What's happened so far is that there is an empty 5x2 subplot and below displays each graph individually. Why is this?

Also just a minor issue but would like some clarification. Within my `.plot()` function, why is the last grouped country only being shown in the title? For instance I have 10 countries grouped together for this plot but the title `Suspected vs. Confirmed cases USA` is showing fr each graph.

Looked at a few SO posts and combined a few answers to try to solve my problem but I seem to be going in circles.

Comment: So you have `10` countries and want to plot each country on a separate subplot?

Comment: @QuangHoang Yup!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 5, sharey=True)
for (c,d), a in zip(df.groupby('Country'), ax.ravel()):
    d.plot(x='Date', 
           y=['suspected cases', 'confirmed cases'], 
           title=f'Suspected vs. Confirmed cases {c}', 
           ax=a, subplots=False)
```

Output:

[image]