# Subplotting after groupby with pandas plot

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, subplot

I have a dataframe like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"idx":[1,2,3]*2,"a":[1]*3+[2]*3,'b':[3]*3+[4]*3,'grp':[4]*3+[5]*3})
df = df.set_index("idx")
df
     a  b  grp
idx           
1    1  3    4
2    1  3    4
3    1  3    4
1    2  4    5
2    2  4    5
3    2  4    5
```

and I would like to plot the values of `a` and `b` as function of `idx`. Making one subplot per column and one line per group.

[image]

I manage to do this creating axis separately and iterating over groups as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60815052/plotting-with-multiple-y-values-with-subplot-and-groupby).  But I would like to use the `subplots` parameter of the plot function to avoid looping.
I tried solutions like

```
df.groupby("grp").plot(subplots=True)
```

But it plot the groups in different subplots and removing the `groupby` does not make appear the two separated lines as in the example.

Is it possible? Also is it better to iterate and use matplotlib plot or use pandas plot function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can do something like this:

```
axs = df.set_index('grp', append=True)\
  .stack()\
  .unstack('grp')\
  .rename_axis(['idx','title'])\
  .reset_index('title').groupby('title').plot()

[v.set_title(f'{i}') for i, v in axs.items()]
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

Maybe eaiser to simple loop and plot:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(10,5))
ax = iter(ax)
for n, g in df.set_index('grp', append=True)\
              .stack()\
              .unstack('grp')\
              .rename_axis(['idx','title'])\
              .reset_index('title').groupby('title'):
    g.plot(ax=next(ax), title=f'{n}')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Almost there but the code you proposed generates the two plots separately and I would like to have them as subplots of the same figure

Comment: @Heko I think it is probably simplier to loop and plot.

Answer (score -1):

If i understod your question correct, you can access columns and rows in a pandas dataframe. An example can be like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.array(df['idx']) 

a = np.array(df['a']) 

b = np.array(df['b']) 

plt.subplot(1,2,1)#(121) will also work
#fill inn title etc for the first plot under here
plt.plot(x,a)
plt.subplot(1,2,2)
#fill inn title etc for the second plot under here
plt.plot(x,b)
plt.show()
```

edit: Sorry now changed for subplot.

Comment: The i in import should be Lower Case

Comment: Thank you the question was unclear, I edited it. And hope you will understand what I want with the subplots. As mentioned I would like to use the subplots parameter of the plot function and not looping over the columns.

Comment: plt.plot(x,a), x should be Upper case

Comment: @EzzaldeenAlribi i changed it now, was typing on the phone, and didnt bother with it as it was only ment to guide to an answer.

Comment: @Heko Still not quite sure how you want to do it, but pandas plot function is just matplotlib  plot under. "The plot method on Series and DataFrame is just a simple wrapper around plt.plot()"-from docs.